# How can i Import ROS2D library in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, ros, roslibjs

I have a react project for turtlebot3 web controller. I will use ros2dlib but when i install with the command this: `npm install ros2d` and add with this on my vscode python code: `import ROS2D from 'ros2d';`  it give an error like this:
**Cannot find module 'ros2d'**

I use ubuntu 20.04 and here is my package.json file dependicies:

I tried to reinstall my node_modules file with these commands and i reopen my project and terminals:

```
rm -rf node_modules
 rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

then i start my project. but still i can't import the library.

Comment: What is the output of `npm install`?

Comment: changed 1 package, and audited 1503 packages in 5s

247 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details  and some vulnerabity messages i've taken but i restart my terminal so i dont have exact output.